# Battery charging is flickering

Tags: battery, power-management

A few days ago my notebook started to bug around with charging the battery. When the battery is not absent notebook runs smoothly. Until I plug in the battery.

Then it starts to charge but immediately stops and restarts charging and stops and so on. If the notebook is not running battery seems to charge well (LED is not blinking). And LED is not blinking intermittently. Seems to be arbitrary.

Does it have something to do with that? This happens every second.
`[13354.078696] keyboard: can't emulate rawmode for keycode 240`

Comment: This sounds like a hardware question, and not an Ubuntu one.  If it is Ubuntu related, please explain.

Comment: It's as soon as Ubuntu started up .. Before startup or with a live Ubuntu everything works fine. I don't even know what changed since the error happened.

Comment: No, that's strange. Now it happens everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Buying a new battery or let notebook repair under warranty.
Now it happens everytime and it's nothing related to Ubuntu. So please vote for closure.

BTW: i will try some other things at monday. But throughout then this answer is the only eligible answer.

Comment: Just mark your own answer as the answer in a couple of days.  Stuff doesn't get closed if the asker of a question answers, because the asker can mark their answer as accepted

Comment: No worries. I do know how things work here. I'm member for a long time (with other accounts). But thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

The error may or may not have anything to do with the issue you are seeing. What is happening is that your laptop is incorrectly sending acpid events, which results in Ubuntu thinking it is being plugged/unplugged constantly. One solution seems to be to install Keng-Yu Lin's ideapad-laptop, which seems to contain fixes for several laptops. It has not been updated since Natty, but it should still work:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lexical/ideapad
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lexical-ideapad-precise.list
```

Change the lines so they say natty, instead of precise, i.e.:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/lexical/ideapad/ubuntu natty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/lexical/ideapad/ubuntu natty main
```

Now install the ideapad-laptop software:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ideapad-laptop
```

After installing, reboot your computer and see if it makes a difference in either the error or the charging.

Comment: did not help and i think something hardware based is broken.